# Why MatrixPlot give so many colors but only two types of number in data?

Tags: plotting, matrix, visualization

For example

```
MatrixPlot[RandomInteger[1, {10, 300}], Frame -> False]
MatrixPlot[RandomInteger[1, {10, 300}], Frame -> False, ColorFunction -> Hue]
```

[image]

You can see, there are three or four colors in the plot but the data have only two digits (0 and 1).

If draw a small plot, it is normal. (Only two colors)

[image]